# Pass Variable from View to Controller in Codeigniter using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller, parameter-passing

I am working on a project where I need to pass a variable from the View to a Controller's method where I'll be using that variable's value. I have tried the following.

**View**

```
...
$user = 3;
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/studentDashboardController/index?user=$user">
                        My Dashboard
                    </a>
                </li>
...
```

**studentDashboardController (*Method 1*)**

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    if ( isset($_GET['user']) ) {
        $user = $_GET['user'];
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("User taken from GET: ' . $user . '")</script>';
    }
    ...
```

**Output for Method 1**

[image: Output for Method 1]

**studentDashboardController (*Method 2*)**

```
public function index()
{
    ...
    if($this->input->get())
    {
        $user = $this->input->get('user');
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Uid taken from Method 2 ' . $user . '")</script>';
    }
    ...
```

**Output for Method 2**

[image: Output for Method 2]

Any suggestions on how to get the value of this passed variable will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing the PHP notation while printing the $user variable. Update the below line in the View

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/studentDashboardController/index?user=<?php echo $user; ?>">
```